# Struggling to display all items in mongoDB object

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, mongodb

I've created a form that the user can add in a band member. If they want more band members, there's a '+' option next to this field, that gives another line for them to add another member in.

I'm struggling to work out how to display all the band members, as there is a varying amount depending on how many the user will input, but also each member is in it's own item in the object.

I've been advised to nest items, but I'm struggling to get this to work.

/* how my objects look on MongoDB*/

```
_id: 5cff8150a9ba5988c4528346
jam_title: "BRUNT catch up 2"
genre: "Rock/Funk"
date_of_jam: "30 June, 2019"
jam_location: "Pirate Studios, Bristol"
jam_postcode: "BS5 0BJ"
jam_members: "Ed"
jam_instruments: "Drums"
jam_member_1: "Bruno"
jam_instrument_1: "Guitar"
jam_member_2: "Will"
jam_instrument_2: "Bass"
jam_notes: "Lock Jaw"
```

/* how it's coded in on the add page */

```
<div class="row" id="members-section">
        <span class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="jam_member_1" name="jam_member_1" type="text">
            <label for="icon_prefix">Member Username</label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-field col s5">
            <input id="member_instrument_1" name="member_instrument_1" type="text">
            <label for="icon_prefix">Instrument</label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-field col s1">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="new-member_1" onclick="newMember()">+</i></a>
        </span>
    </div>
```

/* how newMember function looks */

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    function newMember() {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        document.getElementById("members-section").innerHTML += `<span class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="jam_member_${[i]}" name="jam_member_${[i]}" type="text">
            <label for="icon_prefix">Member Username</label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-field col s5">
        <input id="member_instrument_${[i]}" name="member_instrument_${[i]}" type="text">
            <label for="icon_prefix">Instrument</label>
        </span>
        <span class="input-field col s1">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="edit" onclick="newMember()">+</i></a>
        </span>`;

}
</script>
```

I'd expect some kind of for loop to sort this, but I can't get my head around how to do this.

Comment: Whoever recommended that you nest the objects probably had in mind something like a jam_members field that would be an array of objects.  Each object would contain fields member and instrument.  The code you showed above is creating the input fields - each time the button is clicked, it adds another set of inputs (of course, it also adds another button).  I would expect a for loop to collect the results and store them into the database or for creating a set number of inputs based on data already present.  Does that help?  Or we may need more clarity around what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DovRosenberg thanks for the advice! Would this mean instead of each new div having a new id, I'd have the same one, then create a for loop in JS to add them to an array, then push it into the Object in mongodb?

Comment: You could do something similar to what it has now - where each div has a separate id with the index in it or give them the same id.  I think best practice is probably to give keep ids unique or drop ids altogether if you don't need them.  You could give them all the same class to make it easy to iterate over them.  In any case, yes - loop over all of them, add them to an array of objects, assign that array to the property in the top-level object, then push to mongo.